# how to make htpasswd authenticate once per session

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

how to make htpasswd authenticate once per session, as If I have a link to the same directory, it asks me to re authenticate.

my directives are:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "installation Page"
Require valid-user
```